# Why excel and sql server calculation is different?

Tags: sql-server, excel

Let's have a look at the picture.

[image]

The result is different even though the expression is the same.

Why does this happen?

I have to follow excel result, what should I have do with sql server?

Comment: @MitchWheat Coz it's the same formula.

Comment: @MitchWheat Okay, but I have to find a solution to make it same as excel. That's my client's order no matter what.

Comment: round the results = 4,693,058

Comment: @MitchWheat I need to get 4,693,057.99610 from sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter whatever the software is 1+1 will always yeild 2 and if its not you should check you calculation again. see below

```
SELECT ((4972000.0000) * (1.0000 - 4.4000/100.0000)) 
         / ((1.0000 + ((36.0000/365.0000)) * (13.0000 / 100.0000)))


RESULT: 4693057.996104
```

To get the result on upto four decimal places Use ROUND() function.

```
SELECT ROUND(((4972000.0000) * (1.0000 - 4.4000/100.0000)) 
       / ((1.0000 + ((36.0000/365.0000)) * (13.0000 / 100.0000))), 4)

RESULT: 4693057.996100
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain why this kind of thinks happen?

Comment: My guess is that since you have only used two decimal places in your query sql server must have assumed it is DECIMAL(10,2) or NUMEIC(10,2) some numeric data type with 2 decimal places. but during calculation when a floating point value was yeild sql server did an implicit conversion to float datatype, which is an imaginary value. and will give you unexpected results.

Comment: @M.Ali: s/imaginary/imprecise/ ?

Comment: Imaginary is an imaginary/imprecise representation of an actual number. There are infinite number of  "numbers" that cannot be presented in exact decimal form so we use an imaginary/imprecise number to represent the actual number. If this makes any sense :)